# dom_import_simplexml() returns an empty object (PHP)

Tags: php, dom, simplexml

So, I want to ultimately create a DOM object for the XML, however, $xml_dom seems to be empty. var_dump shows object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { }. $xml_simple is good. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$get_url_report = 'http://...'; // contains well-formatted XML data
$xml_simple = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($get_url_report));
$xml_dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml_simple);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DOM` doesn't work well with `var_dump()`, for example read [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#86224). Additional there is already a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48527) (for over two years now ...).

The object is probably not empty, even if it looks so. You should be able to use it like described in the manual.

Comment: You're right. The line described in the comment link work. It's very hard to read without the proper indentation though. I may just stick with SimpleXML for now.

Answer (score 2):

var_dump isn't useful for objects such as SimpleXMLElement or DOMElement. Try something like `$xml_dom->tagName` or `$xml_simple->asXML()` to see whether those objects have content.

P.S. you may also use [`simplexml_load_file($get_url_report)`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php) instead of `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($get_url_report));`